# Is it possible to make a command handler case-insensitive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have this command handler:

```js
bot.on("ready", () => {
    //Command Handler

    fs.readdir("./commands", (err, files) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        let jsfile = files.filter((f) => f.split(".").pop() == "js");

        if (jsfile.length == 0) {
            return console.log("Could Not Find Any Commands!");
        }

        jsfile.forEach((f) => {
            let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
            bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
        });
    });
});
```

I want to make it case insensitive, so commands would be easier to type, but I have no clue how.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just use `var input = original.toLowerCase();` to make your code lowercase.

Comment: where exactly do you need to place it, as I get an error of original is not defined?